# How to get First 10 Values of array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have array and i need to print first 10 values of array

MyArray :

```
    Array

        [0] => Hello
        [1] => first
        [2] => nice
        [3] => loost
        [4] => emy
        [6] => rood
        [7] => 1599
        [8] => 34345
        [9] => 1313
        [10] => 45667
        [11] => 5678
        [12] => 35546
        [13] => 8877
        [14] => 3434
        [15] => 56767
        [16] => 7778
        [17] => 9987
        [18] => 8842
        [19] => 1223
```

**array_slice not solve my problem !**
Thanks for your helps

Comment: `$arr[0]` - `$arr[9]`?

Comment: Yes $arr[0] - $arr[10]

Comment: Using [for loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)?

Comment: generate this array by loops YES

Comment: the first 10 is **array 0 - 9**. So print it as `$arr[0]` and so on. You can use loop to make it easier.

Comment: @Eddie Can you give me example

Comment: This can be easily searched, did you do any research for this?

Comment: Why dont you google *How to loop using php*?

Comment: Not any attempt by the OP to solve the problem on his own. Seems more like doing someone's homework .. unfortunately there is no vote close because of pure lazyness...

Comment: _"array_slice not solve my problem "_ - Then you probably did it wrong. However, it's impossible for us to know _what_ you did wrong since you haven't posted _any code at all_. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @derHugo Cool down baby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `foreach()` with counter:-

```
$counter =0;
foreach($array as $arr){
  if($counter < 10){
     echo $arr.PHP_EOL;
  }
  $counter++;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/943912

Answer (score 9):

use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
array_slice($array, 0, 10);
```

---

**Syntax** : `array_slice(array,start,length,preserve)`

**Read** - [PHP: Extract a slice of the array](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_slice.php)

Comment: 3rd parameter should be 10. as it represents length of desired array.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) solves your problem.

```
<?php
    $arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

    $newArr = array_splice($arr, 0, 3);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    print_r($newArr);
```

You see here in the above example that I have Spliced out the first three elements from the array - $arr, this would give me a new array - $newArr with those three elements.

The arguments are:

- The source array -- $arr
- The starting index -- 0
- The length (ie. number) of elements you need to slice -- 3

array_splice() method is effective in a way where you need to edit the source array. In our case $arr would then only contain the elements [4,5].

See if this is useful to your scenario.

Comment: Don't just post a link. You should always include an example or it's simply a comment disguised as an answer. Answers are for _solutions_.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Magnus, Editing it and doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array = array('Hello','first','nice','loost','emy','rood',1599,34345,1313,45667,5678,35546,8877,3434,56767,7778,9987,8842,1223);
$i =  0 ;
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    if($i <10){
    echo $value.'<br/>';
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

**Output**

Hello

first

nice

loost

emy

rood

1599

34345

1313

45667

Answer (score -1):

I think this is better.

```
 # $myarray is the array 
 # you want to search
 $count = 0;
 foreach ( $myarray as $item ) {
   if ($count < 10)
      echo $item;
   $count++;
 }
```

Comment: If the array only contain 9 or less, then no elements will be printed at all.

Comment: Yes. Since the question requested for the first 10 values.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson . I just fixed it.